# Using TFTP in Android, Works fine out of android, Hangs on sendFile in android

Tags: java, android, tftp

It all compiles fine and works like a charm, However when i set it up in Android it still compiles fine but when gets to tftp.sendFile it just sits there. I've checked the packets with Wireshark and nothing is being sent.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/AsimpleJavatftpclient.htm

What could be the issue here? Spent a few hours debugging and nailed it down to that tftp.sendFile

--

If i let it run for the 60 seconds it just times out with the following

WARN/System.err(2227): Error: I/O exception occurred while sending file.
WARN/System.err(2227): Connection timed out.

So its loading the methods fine

EDIT: And i've got "android.permission.INTERNET" in my manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I worked it out, emulator seems to block it, but it works fine on the device.