# TFTP (Trivial File Transfer Protocol) support on Android

Tags: android, android-networking, tftp

According to my information the SDK does not support directly the TFTP.

Are the any other ways how to deal with the missing API? Was anybody tried to use org.apache.commons.net.tftp? Are there any experiences how difficult is to run this on Android?

Any other GPL solutions for TFTP?

Thanks,
STeN

Answer (score 1):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7702987/using-tftp-in-android-works-fine-out-of-android-hangs-on-sendfile-in-android) refers to:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/AsimpleJavatftpclient.htm

HTH.

Answer (score -2):

i Found one Brilliant URL for FTP that include Sample Source also. Here is the URL

```
[http://www.lysesoft.com/products/andftp/intent.html#download][1]
```

Comment: I don't think that does TFTP.

Answer (score -3):

You get lots of example to download a file using HTTP Methods.

I'm not sure about the FTP services in Android

Comment: Hi, the question is not how to download the file via HTTP or FTP, but if there is some port of TFTP (TFTP is not a FTP) library available for the Android OS.